# How can I disable the label of the bootstrap switcher?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap switcher:

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html

And I would like to set the label width to `0` because I only want to see `ON` and `OFF`, not the white label between. But if I set label width to `0` there is still some pixel of the white label visible.  Do you know a trick to change this? Happy about any help!

```
<input id="switch-labelWidth" type="checkbox" data-label-width="0">
```

[image: what i want to remove]

---

UPDATE:

```
   <link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/css/highlight.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input id="switch-labelWidth" type="checkbox" data-label-width="100">


   <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/js/highlight.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try `<input id="switch-labelWidth" type="checkbox">`, but if you don't need the line of code you posted, just remove it?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but there is still the white Label

Comment: Please edit the post to show some more code and the related CSS

Comment: @Daniel Minett The link I posted shows all the code and css

Comment: Nobody here will download a bootstrap and try to help you, give and get.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Daniel Minett Actually you do not need to download the file, but I will update my answer

Comment: No, it can be done using browser developer tools, but you may have made changes etc...

Comment: @DanielMinett: Updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it using plugin options, but you could do it using some CSS tricks:

```
.bootstrap-switch-label {
    width: 0px ;
    padding: 0px ;
}

.bootstrap-switch-wrapper {
    width: 55px ; // You may need to change this if you do not use the "normal" size
}
```